# Code explanation with strings

Tags: java, string

Okay, so I am trying to be able to explain the answer to the question below to a friend, but I don't know how. I know that the process method doesn't change s and that the answer is ABCD (s is unchanged), but I don't know why. Is it because strings are immutable? My friend thinks it should be CBA. Any help?

```
public void process(String s) 
{
    s = s.substring(2, 3) + s.substring(1, 2) + s.substring(0, 1);
}
```

What is printed as a result of executing the following statements (in a method in the same class)?

```
String s = “ABCD”;
process(s);
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Just try it, don't ask questions like this please it has no use to others

Comment: Your friend wouldn't be a teacher by any chance?

Comment: Your reassignment of string s is local to the function process only. Java passes parameters by value, so the callers reference is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a new value to the variable `s`. This does not change the value of `s` which is passed to the `process()` method, so the program prints

```
ABCD
```

Answer (score 0):

that happens, because you are calling it by it's value, and it doesn't change

you can rewrite your method such as :

```
public static String process(String s) 
{
    return s.substring(2, 3) + s.substring(1, 2) + s.substring(0, 1);
}
```

and then you can use it like this :

```
String s = "ABCD";
s = process(s);
System.out.println(s);
```